# Setting links on title-less objects?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I would like to use title-less object (no picture) but still link to the object URL.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/titleless-objects/

Is this possible?

Example:
"USERNAME created a promise on XXX."

Promise should link to the object URL (but isn't)